# The terminal process terminated with exit code: 3221226356

Tags: c++, sfml

Im working in VScode and building my files with cl compiler provided by msvc. It is a simple application with one main.cpp file and with SFML libraries included.

When i try to build its compiles, but when i run the .exe my program closes and gives this message:

The terminal process terminated with exit code: 3221226356

Don't know what the problem is, can someone help me?

I already looked msdn website for an answer and stackoverflow but i didn't find any. I don't know that the problem could be in my compile.bat or in my task.json or in my main.cpp file.

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
   sf::RenderWindow window;
   window.create(sf::VideoMode(800,608), "WORKS");
   sf::Event e;
   bool running = true;

   std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> shapes;

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       sf::RectangleShape temp;
       temp.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
       temp.setSize(sf::Vector2f(32.0f,32.0f));
       temp.setPosition(i * 32 , 0);
       shapes.push_back(temp);
   }

   while(running)
   {
       while(window.pollEvent(e))
       {
           if (e.type == sf::Event::Closed)
           {
               window.close();
               running = false;
               break;
           }
       }

       window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

       for( auto shape : shapes)
       {
           window.draw(shape);
       }

       window.display();
   }

   std::cout << "ENDING" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

## compile.bat

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
set executablepath=..\bin\
set executablename=game.exe
set compilerflags=/Od /Zi /EHsc /W4 /Fe%executablepath%%executablename%
set includepaths=/I..\includes
set sourcefiles=main.cpp 
set libfiles=opengl32.lib freetype.lib flac.lib ogg.lib vorbis.lib 
vorbisenc.lib vorbisfile.lib sfml-system-d.lib sfml-window-d.lib sfml- 
graphics-d.lib sfml-audio-d.lib sfml-network-d.lib
call cd src
call cl %compilerflags% %includepaths% %sourcefiles%  /link 
/LIBPATH:../libraries/SFML %libfiles%
call cd ..\bin\
call game.exe
```

## task.json

```
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Compile & Run",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "${workspaceRoot}\\.vscode\\compile.bat",
        "args": [],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "cpp",
            "fileLocation": ["absolute"],
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "severity": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        },
    },
```

## FOLDER HIERARCHY

```
Project Folder
|
|
--> .vscode -> compile.bat and tasks.json
|
|
--> bin -> EXE files with dll from sfml for dynamic linking
|
|
--> includes -> SFML hpp files
|
|
--> libraries -> SFML lib files
|
|
--> src -> main.cpp file
```

Comment: Suggestion: take that 3221226356 and turn it into hex. See if you get something recognizable. If not, see if your search engine of choice turns up anything.

Comment: @user4581301 C0000374 is the hex value and it means Heap Corruption Exception, but i don't know how can i solve and there's no answer that fit my needs in google!

Comment: Already solved!! Thanks guys! The problem was that i was linking the wrong lib files with the compiler, i have linked the sfml-system-d.lib files instead of sfml-system.lib ..... when i changed the error was gone!